# how to do a case or if statement if databse field = x then set storedprocvariable = y

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have `tableA` in `Database1` which has a column `Genre` (movie genres only 3)

In my stored procedure I want to somehow do a case or if statement where it checks in `database1.tableA` for the column `Genre` and does the following logic..

```
if genre is horror then 
   set @newvariable = 1 
if genre is comedy then 
   set @newvarable = 2 
if genre is animated then 
   set @newvarible = 3
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: My suggestion is to flowchart your logic and then translate that to code.  Also, take baby steps.  Just do one thing at a time.

Comment: i am using Microsoft sql sever management

Comment: Take a look at the https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx this will get you started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [case statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) to get what you want,

```
   SELECT 
      newvalue  = CASE WHEN genre = 'horror' THEN 1
                       WHEN genre = 'comedy' THEN 2
                       WHEN genre = 'animated' THEN 3
                  END
  FROM 
       tableA
```

This will return you the value you need.

---

**UPDATE**

AS OP need the stored procedure,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spnamehere]
@gameId INT
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;
   SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;

   SELECT
       NewValue = CASE WHEN genre = 'horror' THEN 1
                       WHEN genre = 'comedy' THEN 2
                       WHEN genre = 'animated' THEN 3
                  END
   FROM 
       tablename
   WHERE
       gameId = @gameId
END
```

Comment: that works for me thanks but now I would like to create a function or stored procedure which passes in a gameId and does a check of the genre for that passed in gameId then does the case statmenet and returns the newvalue is this possible

Comment: Check the update. It is stored procedure which check for gameID from table and then get what you want

Comment: Newvalue get selected and returned by the query. and you can do whatever you want to do with it.

Comment: it just keeps returning 0, the logic does look correct

Comment: can I create this as a function instead

Comment: its jut not returning anything

Comment: I need more information as what you are passing as parameter and table structure and its data so I can give  you any   update on this.

Comment: it works but can I execute the stored procedure inside of insert statement